# React compatible JS OAuth Client - Rails Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

Has anyone successfully implemented OAuth using Doorkeeper as Provider [Authorization Code grant type] in React ? what package did you used that acted as omniauth [if you are using RaIls]

Answer (score 1):

I'm no familiar with Doorkeeper, but depending on what you are trying to achieve you might be interested in having a look at [Pizzly](https://github.com/bearer/pizzly/src/clients/javascript). It has a React compatible JS client both to connect and perform authenticated requests to third-party API (e.g. Twitter, Google Sheets, Typeform, etc.)

Here's a demo with the GitHub API + Pizzly using React: https://codesandbox.io/s/pizzly-github-react-demo-rq78z?file=/src/App.js:493-545